# Training Word Vectors on whole corpus?

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, word2vec, word-embedding

I am training word2vec model on my corpus and a friend of mine asked me if it is right to train the word2vec model on the whole corpus? Because when creating word embeddings I am using the whole corpus, so basically I am leaking the testing information to my network in form of these vectors, which is not ideal when training a neural network.

On the contrary, suppose that I am using a pre-trained word embeddings from google or any other source for that matter, if they have used the same document while creating these embedding, which I will be using to test my network, I will leaking the information anyway.

So my question is what is the right way to train the word2vec?

- Separating test and train data before creating word vectors?
- Creating word vectors on the whole corpus?

Comment: It depends 100 % on what you are planning to do with these vectors.

Comment: I have described the scenario above. I am planning to use it for training deep neural networks